# php function in a "do_shortcode" In case there is opening and closing shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a function like this:

```
function example(){

foreach($array ad $ar){
echo $ar[0];
}

}
```

and i would like insert this in a shortcode opening and closing type:

```
echo do_shortcode('[iscorrect]'.example().'[/iscorrect]');
```

How can i do it ?

Thanks and excuse me for my english.

Answer (score 0):

if you are desperate you can do

```
function example(){
    $output = "";

    foreach($array as $ar){
        $output .= $ar[0];
    }

    return $output;
}
```

though i don't think this is the best approach as you could have just called the contents of the function `example()` inside the function which handles the `[iscorrect]` shortcode itself..